# ES6 filter - how to return an object instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have bunch of array of object, I want to get particular object using filter, but I got array using below code.

```js
const target = [{
  name: 'abc',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'def',
  id: 2
}]

const x = target.filter(o => o.id === 1)
console.log(x)
```

Comment: because `array.filter` always returns an `array` (array of all the filtered items), use `array.find` to get the single object.

Comment: please change your title, because you get an array as result of `filter`.

Comment: @MayankShukla thats great piece of information. I used both filter and find many times, but never realised :)

Comment: @NinaScholz Title has been edited.

Answer (score 64):

As said in the comments, `filter` won't allow you to get a particular object from an array - it just returns another array which elements satisfy the given predicate. What you actually need is [**Array.prototype.find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Quoting the doc:

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is
>   returned.

So your code looks like this:

```js
const target = [{
  name: 'abc',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'def',
  id: 2
}];

const x = target.find(o => o.id === 1);
console.log(x); // {name: "abc", id: 1}
```

Comment: awesome, it is the best way to get filtered object from an array :)

Answer (score 5):

array.filter always return array. But you can try this-

```js
 const target = [{
      name: 'abc',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'def',
      id: 2
    }]
   
let obj = {}    
const x = target.filter( (o, index) => {
  if(o.id === 1)
     obj = target[index]  
})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.filter` will return array containing elements from original array that passed test function.

If you are sure that id's are unique simply do x[0] to get result.

Comment: If array is large it'll be just waste of time: `filter` goes through all of the element even though the result is already found. `find`, however, stops right after founding the result.

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy just get first item in retrned as:

```
const target = [{name: 'abc', id: 1}, {name: 'def', id: 2}]

const x = target.filter(o => o.id === 1)
console.log(x[0])
```