# How do you prevent a javascript object from being converted into a length 1 array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on my first solo ReactJS/Redux project and things were going well until I got to a point where I'm using an object in the Redux store that is always supposed to be a single object. When I copy the object from one part of the store (one element of the sources key) to another (the selectedItems key)  that object is being stored as an array of length 1, which isn't the data I'm passing in (it's just a single object). I could live with this and just read out of that store variable as an array and just use element 0 except that when I call another method in the reducer to replace that variable in the store, that method stores the new data as a single object! My preference would be to have everything store a single object but I can't figure out how to do that. Anyway, here's some of the reducer code:

```
const initialState = {
    sources: [
        {
            id: 1,
            mfg: 'GE',
            system: 'Smart bed',
            model: '01',
            name: 'GE smart bed'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            mfg: 'IBM',
            system: 'Patient monitor',
            model: '03',
            name: 'IBM patient monitor'
        }
    ],
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    purchased: false,
    selectedItem: {}
};

// This is called when a user selects one of sources in the UI
// the Id of the selected sources object is passed in as action.id
// This method creates an array in state.selectedItem 
const alertSourceSelect = ( state, action ) => {
    let selectedItem = state.sources.filter(function (item) {
        return item.id === action.id;
    });

    if (!selectedItem) selectedItem = {};
    return {...state, selectedItem: selectedItem};
};

// When someone edits the selected source, this takes the field name and new value to 
// replace in the selected source object and does so. Those values are stored in 
// action.field and action.value . However, when the selected source object is updated
// it is updated as a single object and not as an array.
const selectedSourceEdit = ( state, action ) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        selectedItem: updateObject(state.selectedItem[0], { [action.field] : action.value })
    };
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>  {
        switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.ALERT_SOURCE_SELECT: return alertSourceSelect( state, action );
        case actionTypes.ALERT_SELECTED_SOURCE_EDIT: return selectedSourceEdit( state, action );
        default: return state;
    }
```

Here is the updateObject method (sorry I left it out):

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    }
};
```

Comment: How is your `updateObject` defined?

Comment: This statement is not clear "`However, when the selected source object is updated it is updated as a single object and not as an array`". By `selected source` do you mean making updates to the `sources` array or the `selectedItem`?

Comment: A similar question has already been done on SO. Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46194469/3762855

Comment: @imcastelli, to answer your question: the comment in selectedSourceEdit refers to the key/value pair 'selectedItem'. That is what I meant by selected source. When selectedItem is updated, the value is being stored as a single object and not as an array.

Comment: @Ciro Corvino, you wonderful human being! That was it. Thanks.

Comment: @TimManchester Too good  you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :** `updateObject` is returning object and not array,and you are maintaining `selectedItem` as an array not object

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    }
};
```

---

**Solution :**

Either return array from `updateObject` :

```
export const updateObject = (oldObject, updatedProperties) => {
    return [{
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    }]
};
```

OR make array of returned object

```
const selectedSourceEdit = ( state, action ) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        selectedItem: [updateObject(state.selectedItem[0], { [action.field] : action.value })]
    };
};
```